# For a given clock trigger, how can I retrieve the associated document/spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script

I've built a Google Sheets add-on where users can add a time-based trigger on any spreadsheet they own. The trigger then later calls a function that retrieves some content from an API and adds it to the respective spreadsheet.

It does that by first calling the `PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties()` function and retrieving some information regarding what content to add to that spreadsheet. This information was initially set when the trigger was created. It thus seems that time-based triggers always know to retrieve the properties associated with the document they were created in, without needing to specify the document ID explicitly (the `getDocumentProperties()` doesn't even support a parameter anyway).

What I have trouble with is, given a list of triggers, such as looping from `getProjectTriggers()`, how can I tell which spreadsheet each trigger has been associated with / created from?

PS: I've tried `getTriggerSourceId()`, but for clock triggers this always returns `null` (which is odd, since this would be the perfect function to retrieve that information).

**EDIT: Here's a sample of code:**

```js
    function setTrigger(form) {

    // Use the current document properties to store what kind of data should the trigger fetch
    const props = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();

    // Set Properties
    const currentSpreadsheetId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
    props.setProperty('backupSpreadsheet', currentSpreadsheetId);
    props.setProperty('triggerValue1', form.t1);
    props.setProperty('triggerValue2', form.t2);
    props.setProperty('triggerValue3', form.t3);

    // Create Clock Trigger to run every day.
    const triggerId = ScriptApp.newTrigger('getData')
        .timeBased()
        .atHour(8)
        .everyDays(1)
        .create()
        .getUniqueId();
}

  function getData() {

    // Get the document properties where the trigger was created
    const props = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();

    // Set up object to store backup info for data retrieval
    const data = {};

    // Get spreadsheet id and trigger config from properties
    data.spreadsheet = props.getProperty('backupSpreadsheet');
    data.t1 = props.getProperty('triggerValue1');
    data.t2 = props.getProperty('triggerValue2');
    data.t3 = props.getProperty('triggerValue3');

    // Open the spreadsheet and write the data to it
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(data.spreadsheet);
    writeDataToSpreadsheet(ss, data);

  }
```

The user can use the add-on UI (sidebar feature) to enable such a trigger using an HTML form on any spreadsheet they choose. The form data gets passed to the active spreadsheet's document properties, so that the trigger will be able to fetch any configuration data necessary in order to run (the `PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties()` function always returns the properties for the document where the trigger was initially created, so it's definitely the case that the trigger is associated with that spreadsheet). The user can thus have multiple clock triggers, with the limitation of one per spreadsheet.

Comment: `how can I tell which spreadsheet each trigger has been associated with / created from?` Perhaps look at the trigger handleFunctions

Comment: `function getTriggerInfo() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().forEach(t => {
    Logger.log(`triggerId: ${t.getUniqueId()} triggerHandlerFunction: ${t.getHandlerFunction()}}`);
  })
}`

Comment: I don't think time-driven triggers are associated to a document. Can you provide the relevant parts of the code you're using in order to reproduce this?

Comment: @Cooper `getHandlerFunction()` returns the function which the trigger runs, which in my case is always the same, and does not offer any info regarding the spreadsheet it runs in.

Comment: Well then I believe you're going to have to provide the code that lamblichus has requested earlier in order to us to get a better understanding of your situation.

Comment: @Iamblichus they are. As the [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/editor-triggers#restrictions_2) goes, _Each add-on can only have one trigger of each type, per user, **per document**_.

With regards to the code, it's slightly difficult to paste everything here, as it's a Sheets add-on that uses the sidebar functionality for users to activate or deactivate triggers. I'll try to add something in the main post.

Comment: @Cooper I've added the code to the main post. In this case, ``getHandlerFunction()`` will return ``getData`` for all triggers, even if each one is used on a separate spreadsheet.

Comment: How do you call setTrigger(form) what's the form where does it come from?

Comment: @Cooper The add-on features a [sidebar](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/dialogs#sidebars) that includes an HTML form, which when the user submits it calls ``setTrigger(form)``, creating the trigger and storing the form data in the spreadsheet's document properties.

Comment: I'd recommend communicating with the author of the addon.  This one of the reasons I'd rather write my own stuff.  I hope lamblichus can help you.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am the owner of the addon :) But cheers for the chat!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Issue:

I don't think there's a direct way to retrieve this, since `getTriggerSourceId()` returns `null` for time-driven triggers, as can be seen in the [method docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger#gettriggersourceid).

That's because, unlike other kinds of trigger, the event that caused this to fire is not related to any document (unlike e.g. Sheets edit, Forms submission, etc.), and that's what [TriggerSource](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger-source) is about:

> An enumeration denoting the source of the event that causes the trigger to fire.

#### Workaround:

Nevertheless, as a workaround, you could use [script properties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service#getscriptproperties) to store information related to which trigger is connected to each spreadsheet when installing the trigger, and retrieve it later.

#### Code sample:

```
function setTrigger() {
  const spreadsheetId = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId();
  const docProps = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
  docProps.setProperty("spreadsheetId", spreadsheetId);
  const triggerId = ScriptApp.newTrigger("getData")
      .timeBased()
      .atHour(8)
      .everyDays(1)
      .create()
      .getUniqueId();
  const scriptProps = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  const newProp = {triggerId, spreadsheetId};
  let triggerIdsProps = scriptProps.getProperty("triggerIds");
  if (triggerIdsProps) {
    triggerIdsProps = JSON.parse(triggerIdsProps);
    triggerIdsProps.push(newProp);    
  } else {
    triggerIdsProps = [newProp];
  }
  scriptProps.setProperty("triggerIds", JSON.stringify(triggerIdsProps));
}

function getSpreadsheetTrigger() {
  const spreadsheetId = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId();
  const scriptProps = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  const triggerIdsProps = JSON.parse(scriptProps.getProperty("triggerIds"));
  const triggerId = triggerIdsProps.find(triggerProp => triggerProp["spreadsheetId"] === spreadsheetId)["triggerId"];
  const projectTriggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  const trigger = projectTriggers.find(trigger => trigger.getUniqueId() == triggerId);
  return trigger;
}
```

Comment: This is correct in that there doesn't seem to be any way to get the document directly from the trigger, though I do consider this to be a bug. In editor add-ons, each time-based trigger is associated with a document (you can test this easily by calling `PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties()` from within the trigger function).

I have [added a feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/207095802) within the Apps Script issue tracker.